# Clojure: defRecord, defProtocol: doing expensive calculation only once

Tags: clojure

### Context

Consider the following piece of code

```
(defprotocol ICat "Foo"
  (meow [cat]))

(defrecord Cat [a b] "Cat"
  ICat
  (meow [cat] (some-expensive-operation a b)))
```

### Question

Is there a way I can throw a let somewhere into there?

I would prefer that (some-expensive-operation a b) is evaluated exactly once, at the time I execute

```
(->Cat a b)
```

so that at the time of (meow cat), it just returns the pre-cached value, rather than recalculate it on the fly. So for example:

```
[1] (let [x (->Cat a b)]
[2]   (meow x)
[3]   (meow x)
[4]   (meow x))
```

I want (some-expensive-operation) to be evaluated exactly once at [1], then for [2], [3], [4] it just returns the old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping the logic to call the expensive operation once in a constructor function, and storing the result as a regular value in the record:

```
(defprotocol ICat "Foo"
  (meow [cat]))

(defrecord Cat [a b] "Cat"
  ICat
  (meow [cat] (:meow cat)))

(defn make-cat [a b]
  (assoc (->Cat a b) :meow (some-expensive-operation a b)))
```

When your code gets more complex I find that you often want to define your own constructor functions in any case.

Note that you might also want to consider wrapping the expensive operation in a lazy sequence or a delay so that it only gets computed if needed.

Comment: A `delay`, not a lazy sequence.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "Constructor" here, we're not talking Java Constructors but rather a wrapper right?

Comment: Constructor here means "function that creates and returns an instance of your record type". It's not a Java constructor, but it does fulfil pretty much the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you function is referentially transparent, then you could wrap your function in `memoize`. At a minimum, you could:

```
(def memo-some-expensive-function (memoize some-expensive-function))
```

and then use `memo-some-expensive-function` in your record.

Comment: This, however, would not get gc-ed when the defrecord is no longer needed.

Comment: I'd prefer something that got "stuck" to the defrecord, so that when the defrecord gets gc-ed, it also disappears.

Comment: You might be able to do that in a record, but I wasn't sure about the scope of the memoisation of the function. Would be worth looking into ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to believe that the simplest way around this may be to

- create a wrapper around defrecord
- this wrapper allows me to specify other fields that I want to recalculate
- and attach these extra fields to the "real" defrecord